# navigation view onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android

I am creating a **collapsing toolbar with navigationview** it works so will but when I use **onOptionsItemSelected** to make a Toast when item of menu chooses, there is no Toast.

Could anyone help me to know What is wrong?

[image]

this is my MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        main_nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        //set navigation view
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, main_drawer_layout, main_toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        main_drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()


    }


    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {

        // set item as selected to persist highlight
        menuItem.isChecked = true

        closeDrawer()
        return true
    }

    // close drawer when item is tapped
    private fun closeDrawer() {
        main_drawer_layout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (main_drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            closeDrawer()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }


    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle presses on the action bar menu items
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.item1 -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Item 1 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

[image: and here is my menu file]

Comment: Would you add also you `menu` file?

Answer (score 0):

The context should be "MainActivity.this" instead of "this" since it's inside of a callback method.

What happens if you set a breakpoint on the Toast line? Is the breakpoint reached?

Comment: when I use  "MainActivity.this" instead of "this" it shows an error "The expression cannot be a selector (occur after a dot)". I'm new android learner I tried to make a breakepoint and debug app but I don't know what you mean by "Is the breakpoint reached?"

Comment: Sorry, I guess it's different in Kotlin. You would use "this@MainActivity".

Answer (score 0):

you must create a new function because it conflicts with the navigationselected. You can create a function called initNavigationDrawer () and call it in oncreate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set breakpoint in your line where you are expecting `Toast`. Maybe there is some problem with logic or `id` of element.

**How to set breakpoint:**

- click near line number and `red dot` should appear
- run in `Debug` mode

[image]

When program stops there it means that evertyhing is correct from logic point of view.

You can also try to change `this` in to `this@MainActivity` to pass proper contex (to method `Toast.makeText(...)`).

Comment: I changed this in to this@MainActivity.. when I set a breakpoint and run in a debug mode the program stops

Comment: @MohamedWessam maybe Toast appears behind the Drawer?